# Why does Geocode API not find this address when Google Maps does?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Having trouble with getting proper coordinates for this address. As you can see, it is just returning generic coordinates for "U.S. 287":

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=7500+U.S.+287,+Ennis,+TX+75119&sensor=false

When typing that address into Google Maps it comes up fine with "Texas Motorplex".

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the link you provided Vaibhav also does not go to the correct place. It needs to be for Texas Motorplex, and 7500 U.S. 287, Ennis, TX is the full address.

@AlexB   This really is the full address (7500 U.S. 287, Ennis, TX). Any other ideas? Does this just happen to be an address that is too tricky for Google?

Answer (score 0):

According to me your address is not complete. For your search query on Google map also it returns latitude longitude for us 287 only.

[Try this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=7500%20U.S.%20287%20Business,%20Ennis,%20TX%2075119,%20United%20States&sensor=true)

Answer (score 0):

In the [link you provide](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=7500%20U.S.%20287,%20Ennis,%20TX%2075119&sensor=false), the `types` parameter is `[ "route" ]`. This means Google didn't find an **exact** location, but only a road with this name.

If you provide a complete address, the `type` parameter will be `[ "street_address" ]`. I think you should complete the address you pass to geocoder server